# JQuery - iterate through elements conditionally to addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have a few input fields that I'm trying to add a class to their parent container if they are not empty.

Here's the CoffeeScript:

```
$(".inputA, .inputB").parent().addClass(->
        if !$(this).is(":empty")
            "input-set"
    )
```

This is successfully appending `"input-set"` to the parent class, but in all cases, not just empty input fields.

:(

Comment: Are you saying you want input-set on the empty inputs or the populated inputs?

Comment: input-set should go on all inputs that have values in the input fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jQuery.filter()`

```
$(".inputA, .inputB").filter(function(){
    return this.value !='';
}).parent().addClass("input-set");
```

Less function calls than using `$.each`

Answer (score 3):

`:empty` will select elements that don't have children. Therefore, using it to conditionally select the parents of certain elements doesn't make any sense.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty

If you're looking to add the class to the parents of inputs that haven't been populated then you could use something like:

```
$(".inputA, .inputB").each(function(){
    if (this.value !== "") {
        $(this).parent().addClass('input-set');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `input` elements are by definition empty..

Read the `:empty` documentation at http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Second you are testing the parent elements and not the `input` ones.. (*and since they are parents, meaning they are not empty they all fit the bill..*)